# How to measure OpenCL readout time?

Tags: java, performance, profiling, opencl

I want to make sure that meassuring time of `clEnqueueReadBuffer()` proper way how to meassure time required to copy data from GPU to main memory. I'm a bit suspicious that `clFinish()` does contribute as well.

I run 100x dot product of 1000000 floats and meassure time by this

```
  // RUN TIME BLOCK
  println( " Running OpenCL program ... " );
  t1 = System.nanoTime(); 
  for (int reps = 0; reps < 100; reps++) {
    clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(commandQueue, kernel, 1, null, global_work_size, local_work_size, 0, null, null);    
  }
  clFinish(commandQueue); // VERSION 1
  t2 = System.nanoTime(); 
  println( " OpenCL Run Time : "+ ((t2-t1)*1e-9)+" [s] " );

  // READ OUT TIME BLOCK
  t1 = System.nanoTime(); 
  //clFinish(commandQueue); // VERSION 2
  clEnqueueReadBuffer(commandQueue, memObjects[2], CL_TRUE, 0, n * Sizeof.cl_float, dst, 0, null, null);
  t2 = System.nanoTime(); 
  println( " Read-out Time: "+ ((t2-t1)*1e-9)+" [s] " );
```

got results

```
 OpenCL Run Time : 2.5124469 [s] 
 Read-out Time: 0.002145424 [s]
```

It seem a bit too Good for me just 2 milliseconds and <0.1% of total time ... the problem of CPU-GPU communication bottleneck does not seems to be so bad.

when I put `clFinish(commandQueue);` inside the `Read-out Time` block I got these results

```
OpenCL Run Time : 1.0892084 [s] 
Read-out Time: 1.4300439 [s]
```

Which on the other hand seems too bad ... it is faster to do 100 multiplications on GPU than copy it by PCI-express ? .... well maybe

---

**Just for completness:**

I used [openclp5](http://code.google.com/p/openclp5/) library for [processing](http://processing.org/) which use [jocl](http://www.jocl.org/) with Java jdk 1.7 on Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit with Quadro FX 580 GPU and

my kernel is simple (no optimization or anything )

```
  String programSource =     
   "__kernel void sampleKernel(                                                 "+
   "__global const float *a, __global const float *b, __global float *c) {      "+
   "  int gid = get_global_id(0);                                               "+
   "  c[gid] = a[gid] * b[gid];                                                 "+
   "}";
```

Comment: Any "clEnqueue*" command is doing just that: _enqueueing_. You're only measuring the overhead of adding something to a queue. 
If you want to know the time the copy takes you'll need to add clFinish. Or use OpenCL events and command queue profiling.

Comment: Hi, It is clear to me that in order to measure RUN-TIME of OpenCL program it is necessary to count `clFinish()` but it is not clear to me, if measurement of `clEnqueueReadBuffer()` does really include ALL time it takes to copy data from GPU to RAM or if part of this operation is already done in `clFinish()`

Comment: `clEnqueueReadBuffer` queues up the work. The work starts asynchronously some short time later. `clFinish` doesn't _do_ the work per-se, it just waits for all work to be done. If the work isn't done, it blocks and doesn't return until it does. If the work was already done (maybe because you went off and computed pi to a million digits) then `clFinish` just returns. So if you time from before you call `clEnqueueReadBuffer` to after `clFinish`, you're timing how long the copy takes, plus some minor API overhead.

Comment: aha OK, I didn't get that `*` in `clEnqueue*` first time. Now I understand that I have to call `clFinish()` ones more after `clEnqueueReadBuffer`

Comment: You don't need to call `clFinish` after `clEnqueueReadBuffer` because you have the blocking flag set. That's an implied `clFinish`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first method of measuring the time to read data back to the host is correct. The second approach would include some computation time.

The amount of data you are reading is `1000000 * sizeof(float) = 4MB`. If this is taking 2 ms, then that means you are achieving a bandwidth of `4MB/0.002s = 2 GB/s`. Why do you think this is too good to be true? Your card supports PCIe x16, which has a theoretical peak bandwidth of 8 GB/s (in one direction).

Comment: OK, thanks, it makes sense. I just took too seriously statements like `GPU-RAM overhead is so big that it pays-off only if you do a lot of operations with each number` which I understand as do al least 10-50 add/mul ops per one float copied to/from GPU. If my processor can do 3 Gflop/s it will pay-off to pass it to GPU already if I do 6 operations per float ( with 2GB/s bandwidth = 0.5 Gfloats/s ).

Comment: The measure is not 100% correct. Probably the operations takes lower device time, the rest is driver overhead, so the transfer is possibly much faster. But as a thumb rule, the measures are correct. Generally speaking you need to put a lot of work to the GPU in order to make the trouble pay off. Not only enough to "hide" the transfer bottleneck. Otherwise, the driver usage in CPU and the overheads will make it no worthy. BTW, you are running 100 operation vs 1 read, usually 1write+1run+1read would be 4ms IO and 25ms operation, that is a lot of IO %.